# clang fails to deduce function template parameter with packed variadic parameters

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

```cpp
#include <tuple>

template<std::size_t... Is, std::size_t... Js>
auto test(std::tuple<std::index_sequence<Is, Js>...>) {}

int main()
{
    test(std::tuple<std::index_sequence<0, 0>>{});
}
```

You can see the compile result of each compiler here: https://godbolt.org/z/z6TEWxn49

The latest GCC and MSVC compiles this code but clang doesn't.

I cannot find why clang fails, so I'd like to make an issue report, if it's clang's bug.

Is clang right by standard? Or, is it a bug of clang?

Comment: Use `std::integer_sequence<std::size_t, Is, Js>` instead of the alias `std::index_sequence<Is, Js>`. The problem here is that it probably is underspecified in the standard how deduction against alias templates (such as `std::index_sequence`) is supposed to work, i.e. whether it is an non-deduced context or whether it is substituted before deduction (and then later substituted again to check validity).

Comment: @user17732522 The issue is not the alias, the issue is the two parameter packs. Try with only one, and clang happily compiles.

Comment: @Holt If using `std::integer_sequence<std::size_t, ...>` instead, even clang manages to deduce both: [example](https://godbolt.org/z/drsPx4oKP)

Comment: @Holt I am not sure whether there is an additional issue with the number of packs. I'll check the standard again.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes, actually clang fails miserably with a single pack and two (or more) index sequences in the tuple.

Comment: @user17732522 I don't think there is an issue there, I initially misread the declaration which is why I thought it was the problem.

Comment: After a bit of research I think it isn't really under-specified and should work, but there are quite a few details I am not sure about.

Comment: @Jarod42 The unpacking is outside `index_sequence`, so `Is` and `Js` must be of the same size and all `index_sequence` must contain 2 values.

Comment: Could this relate to [DRs on equivalence for alias templates](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#1286)?